# Symfony2 & Assetic: Invalid configuration for path "assetic.bundles.0": "AcmeSiteBundle" is not a valid bundle

Tags: php, symfony, assetic

I'm working on a project given to me by another developer.  My task is to convert hard-coded asset references to assetic references.  When I try to run `app/console assets:install` I get the following error:

> [Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\Exception\InvalidConfigurationException]
>     Invalid configuration for path "assetic.bundles.0": "AcmeSiteBundle" is not a valid bundle.

I noticed that there was no directory for that bundle in `web/bundles`, so I simply ran `mkdir acmesite` to create it.  Unfortunately, the problem persists.

My **config.yml** looks like:

```
# Assetic Configuration
assetic:
    debug:          %kernel.debug%
    use_controller: false
    bundles:        ['AcmeSiteBundle']
    #java: /usr/bin/java
    filters:
        cssrewrite: ~
        #closure:
        #    jar: %kernel.root_dir%/Resources/java/compiler.jar
        #yui_css:
        #    jar: %kernel.root_dir%/Resources/java/yuicompressor-2.4.7.jar
```

Not sure how to proceed.

Comment: is the bundle registered in AppKernel.php?.. try commenting the whole line `#bundles: ['...']`

Comment: Yes, it's in AppKernel.php.

Comment: Commenting out the bundles line allows other, 3rd party bundles to install their assets, but that doesn't really help me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured it out.  The bundle class file uses a non-standard name.  So, instead of `AcmeSiteBundle.php` it's just `SiteBundle.php`